# Shop Category Pages missing <h1>s

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic, title, seo, e-commerce

My website is using Future Life theme and Woo Commerce. On the shop product category pages, it doesn't display the category name and there are no `<h1>`'s ../nothing to make a `<h1>`.

Does anyone know how I can get the product category to show on the each product category page and make it each shop pages `<h1>`?

Any help would be great. Cheers, Guy.

Comment: You'll probably have to edit them into your theme templates, maybe by making a child theme to override the individual templates you want to change.

Comment: Nah, I need a more simple option. This won't be suitable in the long term